# UIButtons on particular cells spreading over different cells while scrolling because of reuse identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am trying to put few buttons on particular cells programatically. But i am facing a problem like, while i am scrolling the tableview the buttons are spreading over the cells...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"profilecell";


    ProfileTableViewCell *cell = (ProfileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[ProfileTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"profilecell"];
    }






    if (indexPath.row == 5 || indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 11 || indexPath.row == 12 || indexPath.row == 13) {

        int tag = indexPath.row;

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.valueTextView.bounds.size.width, cell.valueTextView.bounds.size.height)];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        button.tag = tag;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(getTheList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.valueTextView addSubview:button];


    }



    if (indexPath.row == 14 || indexPath.row == 15) {

            int tag = indexPath.row;

                UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.valueTextView.bounds.size.width, cell.valueTextView.bounds.size.height)];
                button.tag = tag;
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [cell.valueTextView addSubview:button];


    }



    return cell;
}
```

I tried by putting the button color, when the tableview is loaded first time it showing correct places for button. But after scrolling the buttons are appearing in different indexPaths.

Can anyone please tell me the solution for this.....

Comment: Your `button` seams to have same property expect colour and action right..! Adding button as subview again again may be a problem. try adding your `UIButton` inside `ProfileTableViewCell` from xib or IB, not programatically. I.m not sure. It may help

Answer (score 0):

Cells get reused. You need an `else` that removes the button if it exists.

And never use a cell's indexPath as the button's tag. That fails badly if rows in your table view can be deleted, inserted, or moved.

In the button action method you determine the indexPath from the button's frame, not its tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the cellForReuse() function in your UITableViewCell class and set a default behaviour for the button every time it gets reused.

Answer (score 0):

You should reuse your button rather than always create new one. Do like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"profilecell";

    ProfileTableViewCell *cell = (ProfileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *button;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ProfileTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"profilecell"];
        button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.valueTextView.bounds.size.width, cell.valueTextView.bounds.size.height)];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        button.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.valueTextView addSubview:button];
    } else {
        button = (UIButton *)[cell.valueTextView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 5 || indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 11 || indexPath.row == 12 || indexPath.row == 13) {

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(getTheList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }



    if (indexPath.row == 14 || indexPath.row == 15) {
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For cell reuse, adding subviews dynamically works fine when we reset contentview before loading another type subviews so that existing views shall removed first before adding another set of subviews which will create unnecessary complexity.

But subclassing UITableViewCell & reusing with minimal text changes/property changes is always considered to be best approach.It will also improve scrolling of table & your code will be more readable.

Subclass

```
@interface ProfileTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *button;
}
-(void)updateButtonLayout:(int)index;
@end

@implementation ProfileTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(void)updateButtonLayout:(int)index
{

    if (index == 5 || index == 6 || index == 11 || index == 12 || index == 13) {
        //set color
    }
    if (index == 14 || index == 15) {
        //set frame
    }
}
-(IBAction)getTheList:(UIButton *)btn
{
    //add functionality
}

@end


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"profilecell";


    ProfileTableViewCell *cell = (ProfileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[ProfileTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"profilecell"];
    }
[cell updateButtonLayout:indexPath.row];
return cell
}
```